# Convert &apos; to single quote in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this:

```
<div class="half">
    <ul class="unstyled">
    <% 
    ctr_prodserv = 0
    @list_products_services_array.uniq.each do |products_services| 
    ctr_prodserv = ctr_prodserv + 1
    if (ctr_prodserv == @mod_products_services)
    %>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="half">
      <ul class="unstyled">
    <%end%>
      <li>&bull; <%=products_services-%></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

I have to replace `&apos;` that the user inputted as `single quote` for `<%=products_services-%>`

I tried to research and found out that `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str)` can help? but I don't know how to implement or if I am on the right track.

Comment: What kind of string you are getting with those special characters ? Please share a sample string ?

Comment: I think the sample string is `"'"`, just a single quote character.

Comment: Output is men&apos;s hats it should be men's hats only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
products_services
# => "men&apos;s"
products_services = CGI.unescapeHTML(products_services)
# => "men's"
```

Comment: Not working i tried it to console:

    mic@mic-pc:~/workspace/ror/eypv4$ rails c
    Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
    1.9.3-p392 :001 > x =  'men&apos;s hats'
     => "men&apos;s hats" 
    1.9.3-p392 :002 > CGI.unescapeHTML(x)
    => "men&apos;s hats" 
    1.9.3-p392 :003 >

Comment: try `CGI::unescapeHTML(x)` reference: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML

Comment: Still not working by the way I am using rails 3 version

Comment: its a ruby method so rails should not be an issue. Try `require "cgi"` before this command. Also try it in irb once if its not working in rails console

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve

```
<%=products_services.html_safe-%>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Note that this does not replace `&apos;` with `'` in your string.  What is happening here is without `html_safe` rails escapes `&apos;` to `&amp;apos;` which the browser renders as `&apos;`.  By calling `html_safe` rails does not do that escaping and the browser renders `&apos;` as `'`.  Always be mindful of [XSS](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss) when using `html_safe`.

Comment: **I have to replace &apos; that the user inputted** *`html_safe` method being called in template view code is, 99% of the time, a sign that you’re not doing things right and opening yourself up to problems.* https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2013/12/19/you-never-want-to-call-html_safe-in-a-rails-template/